# REST API Design, RESTful API Naming Conventions

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have resource `Draft` which has the following representation:

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "groups": ["group1", "group2"] 
}
```

I need to design endpoint which would allow to add new groups to `groups`.

For instance, lets say client wants to modify the resource above by adding two new groups: group3 and group4, then, after this operation, the resource should look like:

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "groups": ["group1", "group2", "grpoup3", "group4"] 
}
```

I'm not sure what should be the right URL structure and HTTP method for such operation.

Currently I'm considering the following option:

```
PATCH `/draft/groups/add` 

{
    'groups': ["group3", "group4"]
}
```

However, I'm not quite sure if that's the right choice.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're identifying your draft by its name, and you have several groups in each draft. If that's correct, then [this](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) would be the REST Naming Convention:
`POST /drafts/{draftName}/groups/ HTTP/1.1` - to create;
`PUT /drafts/{draftName}/groups/{groupId} HTTP/1.1` - to update;
`GET /drafts/{draftName}/groups/{groupId} HTTP/1.1` - to get (groupId shouldn't be required in case of collection resource request).

Answer (score 1):

If a `GET` request on `/draft` gives you a list of groups, I would feel that it's probably the most logical to also use a HTTP method on that same endpoint to make changes to the representation.

So given that, I think my first guess on how to change groups in your API would probably be a `PUT` or `PATCH` request on `/draft` itself.